# Android Studio Build Gradle Runnig too long without end

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a project which was working very well on android studio , suddenly it turns not able to build anyway .. It keeps telling Build Gradle Runnig without any result for 30 min !

I tried to clear .gradle file of project without result.

I tried to uninstall android studio and clean all its files from user directory  AndroidStudio 2.1 and .gradle files and also no result.

This problem occures only with this project and others working fine on android studio ..

What should I do to make my project build again ?!

Answer (score 0):

I had that once when I updated the gradle wrapper. It really took 45 minutes to download that 16MB or so. I had to that time some network issues with their repo servers.

Try to run in the console `gradlew aR` and see what happens. If you see there hundreds of dots you need to wait if there happens nothing kill all java processes and try again.

Comment: I opened gradlew aR and see hundreds of dots and then what after ? I waited untill finishing all download .. when try to build my project still take too long without any run !!

Comment: This is an initial download if it is compleated the real compile process will be done (depending on your project) within 5 minutes

Comment: It is completed but the project still not running .